# read.csv2() unexpectedly breaking a row into two rows?

Tags: r, read.csv

The csv file to import has 134 row and each row having different number of columns. link to file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz9mIfU-AcbrVlZpRnpkd2hYMjA

R command used to import:

```
allConsecCounts <- read.csv2("pathToFile/ConsecCounts.csv",header = FALSE,sep=",",fill = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE,allowEscapes = TRUE)
```

**Problem:** the second last row is being unexpectedly split into two rows.

(*note: when the file to read is just trimmed to last few rows, then it is being read correctly, i.e. the second last row is not broken into two row*).

Kindly suggest

Thanks

Comment: I get 134 rows as expected.

Comment: Try fread from data.table package

Comment: Thanks @RyanMorton for letting me know. However its still not working on my system. I hope it is not due to some setting which is causing rows greater than particular length to be split since it seems that the split row is indeed the longest one.

Comment: Thanks @Shashank but fread only works for same number of columns.

Comment: Well, it may not have anything to do with your code.  Sometimes, when I have split rows, it's usually how I've stored the data. Maybe try saving the data in a different file format and try reading the data using the appropriate read.xxx() command.

Comment: Thanks all. i tried changing it to tab separated data which didn't help either. Eventually, I circumvented the issue by filling NA's in data to make it equal columns (in Java). Now its being read correctly. Lesson being not to trust R to fill in NA's correctly for irregular data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not have a rectangular data set and data tables, matrices and data frames all require rectangularity in R. You have options, which you may or may not like:

You could read in a list of nested lists (pseudo-Json) and query against it, Which may not be all that easy
Or use a loop and
`readLines` , setting each line equal to the first occurrence which seems to be the row name.

If the entries are ordered, you can use `name[1]` and `name2[1]` to access what would be the same location in a table, a least until you run out of traditional table space on the very long rows.

But this way each variable could have a differing number of objects in its list.

Comment: Thanks @bethanyP. Indeed readLines is another way to go, which i tried initially and then gave up as it required more work (loops, string splitting, etc) to do the same thing as data frames/tables do. However, what puzzles me is the apparent erratic behaviour of read.csv2 since technically it should also be able to handle irregular column size by properly inserting NAs.

Comment: I did some investigating with that and it did not work for me either. And it clearly shifts the first row name up, and then adds a VALUE from the second-to-last  REAL row as a row name for the wrapped row...If you know how long each of the rows is, you can explicitly give the dimensions and tell it to add NA's. How are you using the data?

Comment: yes. I did the same. I circumvented the issue by filling NA's in the data to make it equal columns (in Java). Now it is being read correctly and everything works in R. The data is mostly used as grouped by categories (i.e., extracted from row labels) and some transformations done using data.table and reshape2 packages. And then aggregation and distribution stats/plots are being generated. Thanks.